# how to filter a array of object by another object as key in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects

```
let allData = [
  {title:"Adams",age:24,gender:"male"},
  {title:"Baker",age:24,gender:"female"},
  {title:"Clark",age:23,gender:"male"},
  {title:"Davis",age:23,gender:"female"},
  {title:"Ghosh",age:23,gender:"female"},
  {title:"Adams",age:23,gender:"male"},
  {title:"Irwin",age:25,gender:"male"},
]
```

and list of filter in a Object like this

```
let filters = {
  title:{filterTerm:[]},
  gender:{filterTerm:["male"]},
  age:{filterTerm:[23]}
}
```

i want to apply multiple filters on top of allData i tried using Array.some with Array.includes but it is not working when with multiple filters items below is my code

```
const getFilterRows = (rows, filters) => {
    let filterCols = Object.keys(filters)
    if (filterCols.length == 0) {
        return rows
    }
    else {
        let filteredR = rows.filter(i => {
            return filterCols.some((s) => {
                return filters[s].filterTerm.includes(i[s])
            })
        });
        return filteredR
    }
}
```

```
let filterd = getFilterRows(allData,filters)
```

expected output

```
[  
 {title:"Clark",age:23,gender:"male"},
 {title:"Adams",age:23,gender:"male"},
]
```

Comment: What's your filtering criteria? Is it an OR or an AND condition, i.e. must be "male" AND "23", or "male" OR "23"? Will there be multiple items in the `filterTerm` subarray? If you do, what does `age: { filterTerm: [23, 25] }` mean: an age range, or...?

Comment: And if it's `AND`, your `title` filter will filter out everything, since there's nothing to match. You probably want to ignore filters with an empty `filterTerm`.

Comment: updated question with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map each key from `filters` and filter `allData` based on if `filterTerm` includes the item being searched, ignoring the filter if `filterTerm` is empty.  Below example would also allow you to add more items to `filterTerm` if needed.

```js
let allData = [
  {title:"Adams",age:24,gender:"male"},
  {title:"Baker",age:24,gender:"female"},
  {title:"Clark",age:23,gender:"male"},
  {title:"Davis",age:23,gender:"female"},
  {title:"Ghosh",age:23,gender:"female"},
  {title:"Adams",age:23,gender:"male"},
  {title:"Irwin",age:25,gender:"male"}
]

let filters = {
  title:{filterTerm:[]},
  gender:{filterTerm:["male"]},
  age:{filterTerm:[23]},
}

const getFilterRows = (rows, filters) => {
  return rows.filter(row => (
    Object.keys(filters)
      .map(key => filters[key].filterTerm.length ? filters[key].filterTerm.includes(row[key]) : true)
      .every(Boolean))
  )
 }

let filtered = getFilterRows(allData,filters)

console.log(filtered)
```